# How to count a PIC master/slave in assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

Hi there I have no idea how to calculate PIC Master and Slave correctly.
My PIC Master is 20h and PIC Slave is 0A1h and I need to change it to 40h for PIC Master

This my Master controller initialization (base vector 32)

```
mov AL,11h          ; ICW1 is a ICW4
out 20h,AL          ;
mov AL,32           ; ICW2 : base vector
out 21h,AL          ;
mov AL,4            ; ICW3: Slave conected to lvl 2
out 21h,AL          ;
mov AL,1            ; ICW4: 80x86, need EOI
out 21h,AL          ;
mov AL,0FCh         ; interrupt mask
out 21h,AL          ;
```

Comment: The PC/AT has two 8259A PICs, at I/O addresses 20h/21h and 0A0h/0A1h.  Your code looks like the setup for the "master" at 20h/21h.  When you say "*change it to 40h for PIC Master*", do you mean the I/O address or the Interrupt Vector ?

Comment: The I/O port address can’t be changed. If you want to change the base vector, just change 32 to 64 in the line with the comment “base vector”.

Comment: @ChrisHall yes for the interupt Vector I can publish full code is it necesary.

Comment: Well, `mov AL, 32` `out 21, AL` is setting the Base Interrupt Vector (to 20h)... so, as @prl already said, change the 32 to 64 (or 40h) to set the Base Interrupt Vector to that.